# SQL Server - Using tinyint with enum

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Suppose that I have a SQL Server database that, amongst other tables, has a table named `Mail`, which has  the expected recipient, sender, message body, etc. associated with it, one of these being the property `Priority`, which basically indicates if a mail has a high, normal, or low priority of being sent. Since I'll be only using these small amount of values (and if more were to be added it wouldn't be that many), I decided to make Priority a `tinyint` type, while  in my code I'd represent is an `enum` type.

My question is, what is the right way to insert and retrieve this property when calling the database? In the case of retrieval (using a `DataRow`) I have:

```
mail.Priority = (MailPriority)(byte)row["Priority"];
```

And for inserting:

```
parameter = new SqlParameter("@Priority", SqlDbType.TinyInt);
parameter.Value = (byte)mail.Priority;
statement.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

(Where statement is a `SQLCommand`).

So would this work, and is it the right way to do it? I figured that using `tinyint` would be okay, since the possible values can't be that many, but I don't know if `int` would be fine, better in terms of performance, or more commonly used, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Performance and space are not the same.
From a performance perspective .NET can actually access an Int32 faster.
What you get is space savings in SQL.
And you should also define you enum as byte.

```
public enum enumSVMV : byte { SV = 0, MV = 1, none = 2 };
```

Comment: Does it make a difference defining the enum as a byte?

Comment: Why would you not want the enum to be consistent with SQL?

Comment: Fair enough. Would I have to change my code in the case of retrieval and inserting, though? Which I assume is correct, since you didn't mention it.

Comment: The way to find out is to test.  You don't have to change the enum to byte.

Comment: The dummmy tests seem to work fine. And since you told me about defining the enum type as byte and space saving in SQL (which I didn't know of), I marked this as the answer. So thank you.

Comment: So actually byte on the enum hurts performance but I will take that any day for data integrity.  What if you used Int and a future developer decided to use 1000 and greater for any error values?